# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register_forward_hook' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have been getting this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register_forward_hook' when I run my code. I believe that there is something wrong with my function but not too sure what is the problem. If not is there a better way to get the feature vectors? I am trying to extract the Feature Vectors from a pretrained model from a resnet pretrained algorithm. Help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import datasets, transforms,models
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn

import torchvision.utils as vutils
from io import open
import os
from PIL import Image
import sys

import models.resnet as ResNet
import models.senet as SENet

import torchvision.models as models
import pickle

import pandas as pd

import sklearn.metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from models import resnet, resnet50_ferplus_dag, resnet50_ft_dag, resnet50_scratch_dag, senet, senet50_ferplus_dag, senet50_ft_dag, senet50_scratch_dag, vgg_face_dag, vgg_m_face_bn_dag

model = resnet50_ft_dag.resnet50_ft_dag(weights_path='Weights/resnet50_ft_dag.pth') # RESNET MS1M


layer = model._modules.get('avgpool')

model.eval()


scaler = transforms.Scale((224, 224))
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])


to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()


def get_vector(image):
    
    # Load image
    img = Image.open(image)
    
    # Create Pytorch variable with transformed image
    t_img = Variable(normalize(to_tensor(scaler(img))).unsqueeze(0))
    
    # Create a vector of zeros that will hold our feature vector
    # Outputsize of 2048
    my_embedding = torch.zeros(2048)

    # Define a function that will copy the output of a layer
    def copy_data(m, i, o):
        my_embedding.copy_(o.data)          

    # Attach that function to our selected layer
    h = layer.register_forward_hook(copy_data)
    
    # Run model on transformed image
    model(t_img)

    # Detach our copy function from the layer
    h.remove()
    
    # Return the feature vector
    return my_embedding

get_vector('C:/Users/Public/Documents/DIN_Image/average_images/' + list_dir[2])
```

Comment: `layer` is None

Comment: what do you mean by none?

Comment: It appears that `model._modules.get('avgpool')` returns `None`. Are you sure your model has the avgpool layer?